# How can I install development tools (e.g. git, python, gcc) for a single user without requiring admin privileges?

Tags: macos, homebrew, high-sierra, development, macports

I've just done a fresh install of High Sierra and was about to embark on setting my development environment back up. However, I wanted to ask the community if anyone's investigated a way to do this that can be isolated to a single user account and doesn't require administrative privileges.

I'm trying to avoid installing Xcode and the command line developer tools since that seems to be something that eventually needs to be worked around rather than actively used. My meaning there is that, in the past, I've had to deal with installing my own versions of python, git, etc. that may be different versions and conflict with the "xcode versions" of these tools. I don't want to be beholden to Apple's upgrade cycle for Xcode to determine which versions of some of those core tools I'm using.

I've used both MacPorts and Homebrew in the past, but I seem to recall both either (a) requiring Xcode command line tools or (b) not having an easy way to install it without requiring administrative privileges so it can write binaries or symlinks somewhere outside of `/Users/<my-username>`.

So, how can I freely install native, packaged macOS versions of common development tools without being beholden to Xcode or having to give some installer administrative privileges?